# Where does LuaTeX break my trivlist into pages

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, boxes

I have some verbatim text

```
Line 1
Line 2
...
```

which is basically turned into a `trivlist`.

```
\trivlist
\item
\hbox{\MyPrefix Line 1}
\hbox{\MyPrefix Line 2}
\hbox{...}
\endtrivlist
```

I want `\MyPrefix` to be empty except for the first line and every top line of a new page, where it is a 0 width and 0 height box which contents depends on the line number.
How can I know which `\hbox{...}` will be at the top of the page and how can I build the correct prefix accordingly ?

Comment: My guess: you need two passes. Use zref or something to get the current page number, then on the second pass check if the current page number is different from the last page number. If it modifies the content somehow then you need a third pass, and repeat until it converge.

Comment: since `\hbox` does not start a paragraph none of the paragraph settings of `\trivlist` or `\item`are used here